# Jquery date picker not working from second time

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am using jQuery date-picker for date field. Date picker date change based on select list value. My date picker date set first time. But when I change select list value again it goes empty.

```
 <select id="quarter" class="form-control valid" name="quarter" aria-invalid="false">
<option value="" data-start-date="" data-end-date=""> Select Quarter</option>
<option value="FY18 Q1" data-start-date="2017-04-01 00:00:00.0" data-end-date="2017-06-30 23:59:59.0" > FY18 Q1</option>
<option value="FY18 Q2" data-start-date="2017-07-01 00:00:00.0" data-end-date="2017-09-30 23:59:59.0" > FY18 Q2</option>
<option value="FY18 Q3" data-start-date="2017-10-01 00:00:00.0" data-end-date="2017-12-31 23:59:59.0" > FY18 Q3</option>
<option value="FY18 Q4" data-start-date="2018-01-01 00:00:00.0" data-end-date="2018-03-31 23:59:59.0" > FY18 Q4</option>
<option value="FY19 Q1" data-start-date="2018-04-01 00:00:00.0" data-end-date="2018-06-30 23:59:59.0" > FY19 Q1</option>
<option value="FY19 Q2" data-start-date="null" data-end-date="null" > FY19 Q2</option>
</select>
if(startDate && startDate != 'null'){
    console.log(startDate)
    $("#startDate").datepicker("setDate", $.format.date(startDate,'MM/dd/yyyy'));
}else{
    $("#startDate").datepicker("setDate", null);
}
```

Comment: `But when I change select list value again it goes empty.`-> show us `select list` and it's code.Better to create a working example of your problem. You can use fiddle for this

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. **Show us the code for your latest attempt** and where you got stuck. and explain why the result is not what you expected.  Edit your question to include the code, please don't add it in a comment, as it will probably be unreadable.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: on dropdown change I pick data-start-date and assign it to variable startDate. I got value in console but not on date field.